# Load configurable product with preselected options of any one of simple product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, configurable-product, swatches

How to load configurable product with preselected options of any one of simple product?

**For example**

I have a configurable product `http://host/product/1`.

It have 2 associated simple products `http://host/product/2` and `http://host/product/3`.

Whenever configurable product page load, I need to display the preselected options of `http://host/product/2`.

Can anyone share hints to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Following this article by Daan van den Bergh you can do exactly what you need: 
https://daan.dev/magento/2/redirect-simple-products-configurable-parent-attributes-pre-selected/

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm in same situation.
Below is my implementation (not completed yet but I believe to be "clean" solution):

- override
  Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
  in custom module, adding code to check how many child products the configurable product has (if only one, then don't render the options).

This also requires adding a Plugin class for the swatches module due to stupid magento2 hard coded template paths, refer to
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4400

- create custom js component that takes the child product id available in the phtml template. This component will set the value of the 
  "selected_configurable_option" hidden input field to that product id.

This should be enough to allow customer to set quantity and add to the cart.

I usually do only backend side so am looking up minimal way to create this js component (or do it inline if possible).

FYI this is not a fully tested or complete solution as I haven't check what these overrides do when customer is editing their cart or browsing category products.

I'm still working on it as of this post.

Answer (score 0):

This free module does the job! :) https://github.com/magepow/magento-2-configurable-preselect 
it also has an option to view preselected options in listing page